# MacBook Air OS X Lion will not update

Tags: macbook-pro

I am unable to download any writing apps because my MacBook Air OS X Lion is at 10.7.5 and isn't recognising that there is any other updates so i cannot update my MacBook to 10.11 to download any apps.

Comment: Which specific MBA model are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a first generation MacBook Air, the latest OS it can run is 10.7.5

Source: [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-2-duo-1.8-13-specs.html)